# How to PIVOT multiple columns using SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot

I just wrote a query (for SQL Server) that is returning this output:

| VendorId | Category | FirstSaleDate | StoreId |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Car | 1/1/2021 | 12 |
| 1 | Clothes | 1/2/2021 | 13 |
| 1 | Toys | 1/3/2021 | 14 |
| 1 | Food | 1/4/2021 | 15 |
| 1 | Others | 1/5/2021 | 15 |

But I actually need the following output

| VendorId | Car | StoreId_car | Clothes | StoreId_clothes | Toys | StoreId_toys | Food | StoreId_food | Others | StoreId_others |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1/1/2021 | 12 | 1/2/2021 | 1/2/2021 | 1/3/2021 | 14 | 1/4/2021 | 15 | 1/5/2021 | 15 |

I am new to SQL Server, but I saw that this might be possible by using two PIVOTs. I really need your help to find the right syntax.

[scenario and output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EVan4.png)

Comment: Question is still vague. Can you please format your desired output. So that it is easy to understand

Comment: So are the number of Categories fixed? There are many examples of povits online and in StackOverflow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to pivot twice and combine the results, e.g.:

```sql
-- Setup example data...
drop table if exists #Example;
create table #Example (
  VendorId int,
  Category varchar(10),
  FirstSaleDate date,
  StoreId int
);

insert #Example (VendorId, [Category], FirstSaleDate, StoreId)
values
  (1, 'Car', '2021-01-01', 12),
  (1, 'Clothes', '2021-01-02', 13),
  (1, 'Toys', '2021-01-03', 14),
  (1, 'Food', '2021-01-04', 15),
  (1, 'Others', '2021-01-05', 15);

-- Pivot data...
with FirstSales as (
  select VendorId, Category, FirstSaleDate from #Example
), Stores as (
  select VendorId, 'StoreId_' + Category as Category, StoreId from #Example
)
select
  FirstSales.VendorId,
  Car, StoreId_Car,
  Clothes, StoreId_Clothes,
  Toys, StoreId_Toys,
  Food, StoreId_Food,
  Others, StoreId_Others
from (
  select VendorId, Car, Clothes, Toys, Food, Others
  from FirstSales
  pivot (min(FirstSaleDate) for Category in ([Car], [Clothes], [Toys], [Food], [Others])) as pvt
) as FirstSales
join (
  select VendorId, StoreId_Car, StoreId_Clothes, StoreId_Toys, StoreId_Food, StoreId_Others
  from Stores
  pivot (min(StoreId) for Category in ([StoreId_Car], [StoreId_Clothes], [StoreId_Toys], [StoreId_Food], [StoreId_Others])) as pvt
) as Stores on Stores.VendorId=FirstSales.VendorId;
```

Comment: Can we do it without the CTE? Just because I will have to add this query to a MERGE

Comment: Yes, you can do it without a CTE. Just replace the `from FirstSales` and `from Stores` with subqueries using the CTE select statements.